# Angular Keycloak Service Initialization

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak-angular package and in the setup instructions the initialization of the service becomes during app initialization.

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { initializer } from './utils/app-init';

@NgModule({
  imports: [KeycloakAngularModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now the initializer function is like this one:

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => keycloak.init(
        {
          config:   {
                        url: "some-authentication-url",
                        realm: "some-realm",
                        clientId: 'some-app' 
                    }
        }
    );
}
```

Is it possible to do the above initialization during runtime of my application? I need to do this because the realm name is not known from the beginning.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm trying to do something quite similar, but the closest I've come is storing the configuration to session storage on the unauthed landing page, and then pulling the data in when the user hits the login/authed pages.  Problem is that while this works (I can see the keycloak initialization pulling in the correct values and I get redirected to the correct keycloak login client), once logged in I get thrown into a bizarre infinite redirect loop between the web ui and keycloak.